# how to 'CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(...) THEN DATEDIFF(..)..' without grouping by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using this query:

```sql
select a.username, count(*)
from A a inner join (
    /* duplicate results will be removed by the union */
    select username, date from B union
    select username, date from C union
    select username, date from D union
    select username, date from E union
    select username, date from F
) u on u.username = a.username
where a.min_date >= u.date
group by username;
```

which gets the count of unique dates across some tables and groups them by username.

I want to get the difference of the first date and the last date for each username within an 30 day interval i.e. something like this (but obviously it's not working):

```sql
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, min_date, [Date]) <= 30
THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, min([Date]), max([Date])) ELSE NULL END as diff
```

which tells me I need to groupby min_date and [Date], but this is something I believe I don't want to do. Is there a workaround? If I use some aggregate function on case e.g. MAX(CASE... then I get the cannot use aggregated function containing an aggregate function.

Comment: What do yo mean within a 30 day interval?  You mean every month?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: @Hogan maybe interval was not the correct word, but you can see in the second code block what I mean by it ( to only consider dates that are within 30 days of the min_date)

Comment: min_date is a column or a calculated value?  Do you mean the min(date) or a column called min_date?

Comment: I don't get your questions, it takes like 1' to read the code blocks I provided

Comment: You're quite right, it doesn't take long to read your code. But that leaves us no wiser: "I want to get the difference of the first date and the last date for each username within an 30 day interval" within an 30 day interval of what? The code isn't helping us understand what it is you want to achieve, which is why we ask for sample data and expected results (as text, no images). Rather than us going back and forwards trying to work it out, it's far easier if you show us.

Comment: how does this `DATEDIFF(DAY, min_date, [Date]) <= 30` not answer your question?

Comment: Because some of the "not working" code has `min` or `max` aggregation and some of it doesn't so it's hard to see exactly what you want without sample data and expected results. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/14868997